# Use of Web Speech API in commercial application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webspeech-api

I want to create a commercial web application based on speech recognition.  I have found the Web Speech API (https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/) currently only supported by Chrome.

Can I use this API for free for my commercial application? Is there a limit on the number of uses per day, or a free quota that I must not exceed?

Answer (score 0):

From https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-speech-api/2013Jul/0001.html

> To clarify, commercial apps that use the Web Speech
> API https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html can
> be used on browsers that support it, such as Chrome (for complete
> details, see the Terms of Service in the About menu).

References:

- https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-html5/c/31rlwXxzQGs/m/BbeSI_waCQAJ

More information can be searched here:

- https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-html5/search?q=web%20speech%20api